# Invoking and overloaded template function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Assuming I have 2 overloaded methods in a class shown below
Please ignore the need for such a weird overloading of methods it is something I came across recently

```
    class A{
      public:

        //Lets call this method 1
        int GetVal(bool isCondition) const
        {
             //do something and return val
        }

        //Lets call this method 2
        template<typename T>
        int GetVal(T expression)
        {
            //do something using expression
            //and return val
        }

    };

int main()
{
    A obj;
    int val = obj.GetVal(false) << std::endl; //I want to invoke method 1
}
```

In the `main()` function, I want to invoke method1 and not method2.
How can I achieve this?
Thanks for reading

Comment: Sorry I had to make a change:Method 1 is const

Answer (score 3):

> In the main() function, I want to invoke method1 and not method2. How can I achieve this? Thanks for reading

And it's exactly what you get calling

```
obj.GetVal(false)
```

because `false` is a `bool` so it's an exact match for the not-template method. And when a call matches with a template method and a not template method, the not-template method (in case of **exact** match) is preferred.

The real problem is: how to invoke the method2 calling it with the type (`bool`) of the not template method (method 1) ?

The answer (a possible answer) is: add a `template` calling it

```
obj.template GetVal(false)
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
 {
   //Lets call this method 1
   int GetVal (bool)
    { return 1; }

   //Lets call this method 2
   template <typename T>
   int GetVal (T)
    { return 2; }
 };

int main ()
 {
   A obj;

   std::cout << obj.GetVal(false) << std::endl;           // print 1
   std::cout << obj.template GetVal(false) << std::endl;  // print 2
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

Given that the OP precise that method 1 is `const` (and method 2 isn't), method 2 become the better match.

The problem can be solved modifying `A` as in Jarod42's answer (adding a not-const not-template method that call the const method or SFINAE disabling the template method 2 when `T` is `bool`) or as in Wanderer's answer (making `const` also method 2).

But if you don't wont (or if you can't) modify the class `A`, you can simply use `static_assert()` directly in `main()`

```
std::cout << static_cast<A const &>(obj).GetVal(false) << std::endl;
```

Comment: (please see edits) Thanks, but thats not the behavour  i see. Method 2 gets invoked in my case

Comment: @user3880248 - I see... yes: if method 1 is `const`, it's different: the template method become a better match. In this case, you can follows the Jarod42's suggestions (static cast or SFINAE) or also the Wanderer way (make `const` also the template method) or simply call `GetVal()`, in `main()` using `static_const`: `std::cout << static_cast<A const>(obj).GetVal(false) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

You might add extra overload:

```
class A{
public:
    // Lets call this method 1
    int GetVal(bool isCondition) const { /* do something and return val */ }
    int GetVal(bool b) { return static_cast<const A&>(*this).GetVal(); }

    // Lets call this method 2
    template<typename T>
    int GetVal(T expression) { /* do something using expression and return val */ }}
};
```

Or use SFINAE for method2 to discard `bool` parameter:

```
class A{
public:
    // Lets call this method 1
    int GetVal(bool isCondition) const { /* do something and return val */ }

    // Lets call this method 2
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<bool, T>::value>, int> = 0>
    int GetVal(T expression) { /* do something using expression and return val */ }}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I know only 2 choices

1. Use all overloads as const

   ```
   //Lets call this method 1
   int GetVal(bool isCondition) const
   { /*do something and return val*/ }

   //Lets call this method 2
   template<typename T>
   int GetVal(T expression) const
   { /*do something using expression and return val*/ }
   ```
2. or as non const

   ```
   //Lets call this method 1
   int GetVal(bool isCondition)
   { /*do something and return val*/ }

   //Lets call this method 2
   template<typename T>
   int GetVal(T expression)
   { /*do something using expression and return val*/ }
   ```

Then Method 1 will be invoked

```
   std::cout << obj.GetVal(false) << std::endl;
```

If you need Method 1 const use Jarod42 second example. It is wokring

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<bool, T>::value> = 0 >
int GetVal(T expression)
{ /*do something using expression and return val*/ }
```